# usercontrol keydown at MVVM silverlight project

Tags: c#-4.0, silverlight-4.0, user-controls

am new to MVVM world ,I have a XAMl like

```
<UserControl x:Class="KeyDownMVVM.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
        <Button Content="Button" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="186,125,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

I want to handel userlcontrol keydown event to catch the keyboadr modifiers and the key , but usin MVVM patern any idea . I use silverlight 4 . and most of tutorials speak about specific control

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend looking into "EventToCommand" in the [MVVMLight](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/) framework. It'll allow you to specify an event that invokes a command on your viewmodel. There are plenty examples of how to use this on SO or other places.